# unwanted pagebreak in footnote

Tags: hyperref, footnotes, urls

I'm trying to reference a long URL in a footnote. I'm usig hyperref-package (which loads automatically the url-package).

```
\usepackage[unicode=true, 
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}
\urlstyle{rm}
```

My footnote looks like this:

```
\footnote{\url{https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2008/04/03iTunes-Store-Top-Music-Retailer-in-the-US.html} - besucht 14.08.2012}
```

The URL is seperated in 2 linex, but the first line is on one page and the second line is on the next page. [image: Page1] [image: Page2]

Do you know how i can fix that issue?

Comment: the first footnote is mentioned in the last line of page 95. the second footnote is at the beginning of page 96.

Comment: These are tough problems: probably your footnote marker is in the last line, leaving space only for one line of the footnote, while moving the marker to the next page would make an underfull page. Try rephrasing the text.

Comment: As I've experienced, this behavior also leads to the problem, that the hyperref link is also applied to the page number on the first page and the header and beginning of the text on the next page.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is difficult to reproduce the behaviour, but I have following suggestions:

1. Try loading the package [bigfoot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bigfoot), which does wonder to the layout of footnote.
2. Try adding the command `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` to increase the type block, or `\enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}` to reduce type block.
3. Try rephrasing the text so the footnote reference is another place in the sentence and on the page.
4. Try adding a `\nopagebreak`at the end of the footnote.

   `\footnote{\url{https://www.apple.com/pr/library/2008/04/03iTunes- Store-Top-Music-Retailer-in-the-US.html} - besucht 14.08.2012 \nopagebreak}`

Comment: "enlargethispage{-\baselineskip}" has made it :) thank you

Answer (score 34):

Setting

```
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
```

should prevent all footnotes from breaking over a page.

Comment: Is it possible to make that command local to one footnote? Normally, if you have several long footnotes, it may be not desirable to hinder all footnotes to split (may give ugly layout)

Comment: yes it can be set anywhere locally and just works in that scope so any surrounding environment would scpe it or `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000 \footnote{...}} if you just want one.